# Setting TimeZone of Java Calendar to device timezone?

Tags: android

How can I construct a Calendar object using getInstance(TimeZone) to use the device's TimeZone?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2037), just using:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

will give you an instance in the user's default time zone (as per their settings). You can determine the time zone from the calendar with:

```
TimeZone zone = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

Other posts have suggested that using `TimeZone.getDefault()` does *not* give this user-default time zone - I don't know about that personally, but it's another option to look into.

Comment: So then `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());`?

Comment: @LuxryMode: No, just `Calendar.getInstance()` - it's already *got* the right time zone, so why would you need to create another one?

Comment: oh ok. Thought it'd have some default time zone that might not be correct on every device.